# How do I call the Config.java in my servlet?

Tags: java

I've been trying really hard to figure out how to bring in this database connection into my servlet, but failed, and hence this posting here.

Basically, I am using this code which I found my this site - one that is taught by BalusC.

```
public class Config implements ServletContextListener {
    private static final String ATTRIBUTE_NAME = "config";
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        ServletContext servletContext = event.getServletContext();
        String databaseName = servletContext.getInitParameter("pract1");
        try {
            dataSource = (DataSource) new InitialContext().lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/TestDB");  
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Config failed: datasource not found", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        System.out.println("contextDestroyed....");
    }

    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        return dataSource;
    }

    public static Config getInstance(ServletContext servletContext) {
        return (Config) servletContext.getAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
    }
}
```

He explained that you have this class and the connection will start once for all the servlets, so I thought it's a good practice to do it.

Now, my problem is that I do not know how to bring the database connection which is set up in the Config, the context.xml file, etc. to work in the servlet.

Here's what I have attempted but it is not working out:

```
Connection con = null;
Config a = new Config();
con = (Connection) a.getDataSource();
DBConnect dbConnect = new DBConnect();
con = dbConnect.getConnection();                        

stmt = con.createStatement();                   
rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM members");
```

I hope someone can tell me how to bring the connection into my doPost Servlet.

Comment: What is `a`  in `con = (Connection) a.getDataSource();`

Comment: Sorry I missed out this line: Config a = new Config();

Answer (score 1):

Better way to use the connection created in `ServletContextListner` is by setting it as a attribute in ServletContext like this :

```
event.getServletContext().setAttribute("connection_name", connection_object);
```

After this, you can use this  `connection_object` in any servlet like this :

```
connection_object = config.getServletContext().getAttribute("connection_name");
```

Comment: The OP's code already includes a reference to the Config instance which has a getDataSource() method. This would be redundant. Look at the OP's code again.

Answer (score 0):

**Your casting datasource to Connection**

```
     Connection con = null;
     con = (Connection) a.getDataSource();
```

Please change to

```
     DataSource dataSource= null;
     dataSource = (DataSource) a.getDataSource(); // Your casting datasource to Connection 

     //get the connection from datasource

     if (dataSource!= null) {
        con = dataSource.getConnection();
     }
     if (con!= null) {
       stmt = con.createStatement();                   
       rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM members"); 
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
 Connection con = ((DataSource) a.getDataSource()).getConnection();
```

Instead of this:

```
 Connection con = null;
 con = (Connection) a.getDataSource();
 DBConnect dbConnect = new DBConnect();
 con = dbConnect.getConnection();
```

Assuming that you have set:

```
Config a = Config.getInstance(request.getServletContext());
```

Comment: I have now included Conig a = Config.getInstance(request.getServletContext()); con = a.getDataSource().getConnection();  But, Tomcat is still gving me error: Reloading Context with name [/Web1] has started
contextDestroyed....
Sep 30, 2013 7:19:53 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/Web1] is completed

Comment: That's not an error. Is your con object working as it's supposed to?

Comment: I think so because the test connection works fine.  Now, I have added autoDeploy="false" and the above problem is gone.  I am getting another error :  Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Oct 1, 2013 8:22:19 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Oct 1, 2013 8:22:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start

Comment: The browser gives me a HTTP 405 error and Tomcat shows another error :Undeploying context [/Web1]
Oct 1, 2013 10:28:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor C:\\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\conf\Catalina\localhost\Web1.xml